# Most Probable Sum for Dice Rolls

Tags: probability, dice

Hey so I discovered this formula for finding out the most probabble result when rolling a certain number of f-sided dice. Could you check it and tell me why it is so?

```
P=[n(f+1)]/2
```

where

P= Most probable sum of dice rolls

n=number of dice

f=number of faces each die has

Comment: looks good. Though $n$ can be equal to $1$ or $0$ if you wish.

Comment: This fails when $n$ is odd and $f$ is even as the formula does not produce an integer.

Comment: This works as it will produce for eg. 19.5 then the two numbers would be 19 and 20.

Comment: That may be the case, but $19.5$ does not equal $\{19,20\}$ so the definition is not really correct.

Comment: This formula is for the expected sum but not for the mode sum.